# Site not saving my number of times visited/logged in

Tags: support

I have noticed over the past several weeks that my logins seem to not be registering.  I have visited every day for almost a month trying to work on my consecutive day badge.  And yes, my name is at the top of the screen when I am logged in.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How odd, because it worked fine for you in September and I don't know of any changes to the login that might effect this. I'll have to ask help from the team on this

Answer (score 1):

[Have a look at this Meta.Stackoverflow question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97)

> login pages, along with a number of other homepage style pages, don't count as "access"

So simply go look at a question and you should be fine!

Answer (score 1):

Usually, what gets people is that they're using the site every day in local time. But consecutive days count **[UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC) days**. For example, if you pause between Saturday morning and Sunday late evening and live in America, you've missed Sunday.

Furthermore, there is some limited protection against automatic downloads counting as a visited day. Being active in any way (posting, commenting, voting, …) definitely counts. In between, the SE team has not revealed exactly what counts as a visited day; I believe refreshing the home page (including its images and other content) is sufficient, and browsing one question is definitely sufficient.

Consecutive days are explained in the [badge FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) under “Enthusiast” and “Fanatic”.

Answer (score -1):

From what I read about this on Meta, for the consecutive day count it's not enough to only login, you also need some minimum level of activity.

I guess accessing a question should usually be enough: that should count as [access to an internal page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66482/164446).

Comment: You don't have to ask a question or anything like that.  I log into travel every day and don't ask a question and it has been fine for the past 80 days.  I log in and browse the questions but it is not counting my days in a row.